# Why does Netflix's "Marco Polo" have the reputation of being a flop?

Tags: marco-polo

I keep reading online that *Marco Polo* from Netflix was a flop, and I don't understand how it's earned this reputation.

Perhaps this myth is spread by competing studios and critics, but I don't see how the facts support that overall assessment. Granted, the review-aggregation site Rotten Tomatoes shows a 30 percent average rating for *Marco Polo* among critics, and one of the directors/producers even said in an interview once that she considers it the biggest failure of her career.

However, Netflix's CEO says it's a hit. While Netflix doesn't release ratings information, we don't have to take his word for it: during that period, Netflix added a record 13 million new members, and their revenue, income and earnings per share were on the rise. The first season cost $90 million to produce, and we don't know how much profit was earned or money was lost.

Rotten Tomatoes’ "Audience Score" metric is a favorable 93 percent for *Marco Polo*, compared with 96% for their *House of Cards*. HBO's highly successful and popular *Game of Thrones* is in the same ballpark. I'm not a fan of *Game of Thrones*, though that's neither here nor there; I only mention it because some people like to compare the two shows, even though I don't see why that is--one is semi-historical fiction and the other fantasy--they're not mutually exclusive.

Is a series a flop just because most critics didn't like it, or even when a producer or director dislikes their own work--doesn't viewership ultimately become the deciding factor in the perception of public opinion? I think of books: many classic novels were despised by their own authors and their contemproary critics, and yet they're timeless and enjoyed by millions. So if *Marco Polo* has millions of fans, how can anyone say in good conscience that the show is a failure? If that were true, why wasn't it cancelled?

Despite the criticism, I for one am delighted that *Marco Polo*'s second season is slated to begin in 2016. I am a fan, I admit I've watched every episode multiple times. I got several friends to watch it too, and they all enjoyed it very much (or at least that's what they told me anyway).

Comment: There is no scientific definition of 'flop' in this context. It's purely opinion. If some say it's a flop, then in their opinion, it's a flop.

Comment: This is a rant by a fan and not a question.

Comment: I understand the subjectivity, but flops are usually cancelled. They lose money. They have no fans. If a show is renewed for a second season at a staggering $100 million, declared a "hit" by the studio's chief executive, on what basis can it be called a flop? Because reviewers piled on it? It's one thing to have an aversion to it, that's opinion, but when popular publications refer to it as a failure, what is their supporting argument?

Comment: I chose to disclose my opinion of the show which does not invalidate the question. What facts can a writer who publishes an article in a publication point to in order to support the view that the show is perceived as a failure?

Comment: This is an opinion piece. How do you define flop? How do you prove why many people don't like it?

Comment: I never watched the show, but I do find this question well researched and on topic. Whether it is a matter of a personal opinion or there is indeed some objective way to answer it, remains to be seen and I hope that the users don't rush to close it. However, I would suggest that the OP elaborates this: "I keep reading online...". If it's from the critics then the RottenTomatoes critics rating of 30% would explain it. If it's from regular people, then not so much.

Comment: Networks cancel great shows and fund crappy ones... it's not really something we can "understand". Clearly, Netflix likes *Marco Polo*, and that's all that's really important, I guess.

Comment: @kuhl No, it's a subjective question that adheres to the 6-pointed guidelines established at Meta Stack Exchange for "good subjective questions." It's a question about how the industry works with regards specifically to this one series. It has nothing to do about any one opinion of the production.

Comment: @sss4r you're asking why critics don't like it. Maybe not completely subjective but it's going to br tough to get a quality answer on 'Why a show is a flop'...

Comment: @kuhl Is a show a flop just because most critics don't like it? Despite every other indicator pointing to the show being a success? I could point to a dozen articles in which the writer states explicitly that the show is a failure as though it were accepted as fact by conventional wisdom, but by what metric? What supports that position? So a journalist can publish that a show is a failure on the sole basis that most critics dislike it? Is that how the movie industry works?

Comment: My question is not at all, Why do critics dislike this program. If that's what you think, then I have not been clear and for that I apologize. I am using this series as an example to gain insight into how the industry operates. What you're saying is that anyone who publishes an article in which they state that the show is a failure, the only response is, That's your opinion, and not, Show me the documentation? Journalism is supposed to be about reporting the truth, not opinion, but evidently that does not apply to movies and TV.... If the director says this show is a flop, then tell me why?

Comment: Maybe it's not a good subjective question after all. Maybe it's unanswerable. In that case, close the question. I can't delete it because of the up-votes.

Comment: @sss4r *"I can't delete it because of the up-votes"* - And you shouldn't either. As apparent from the comments and upvotes, not everyone is convinced that this is a bad or off-topic question at all. Sure, it might need to be fleshed out a little more for everyone to see that it's not just some subjective rambling. But this definitely has potential. Please don't just delete borderline on/off-topic question because of frustration...

Comment: ...The close-voting feature is there for a reason and we can't entertain any kind of subjective rambling (which I don't say this question is). But it doesn't mean that the question has no chance either. That's why it's a feature based on *voting* and which can afterall be reversed if the community thinks the question has changed for the better.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I definitely agree it needs work, and I'm glad you see the potential too--I'd like to see the site contain some quality subjective questions. But even I'm not yet convinced this is one qualifies. It's based on the perception of contradictions and discrepancies surrounding the reception of the show. I am struggling to articulate and defend, and yes, I did become frustrated, and lost confidence, plus it's a time management thing. Anyone is free to make edits, refinements, in order to clarify and hone the definition of the question. Perhaps the idea can be resuscitated.

Comment: Still no need to delete it, though. It is highly positively voted and maybe someone will want to make an attempt at reopening later. There is really no need to delete a closed question when it has a score of +3 and is only borderline closable. But well, your decision (which won't save you from anyone possibly rewording and undeleting it in an attempty to reopen it later, though.)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Thanks, I am still unfamiliar with much of how the process works. I thought I was just helping by doing some cleanup, and perhaps some were right, maybe it is unanswerable, but I'm fine with leaving it open to see if anything ever becomes of it. Thanks.